# Any+Time DatePicker - show popup below field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, anytime

I'm using the Any+Time DatePicker and when I click on the date field, the calendar UI displays **above** the date field. It is obstructing information that would be useful to help enter the date. Is there a way to get the calendar UI to appear **below** the field that has been clicked upon?
My code is:

```
$("#start_date").click(
        function(e) {
            $("#start_date").AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker({ format: '%d-%m-%Y'}).focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    );
```

**Solution:**
comment out line 3051 from *anytime.js* version 4.1112L.The line is:

```
if ( top < 0 )
```

Comment: Does anybody know any setting for my required display type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: comment out line #3051 of anytime.js version 4.1112L

Long answer: The pos() method positions the picker relative to the input field. By default, the method tries to place the picker above the field.  Line #3051 tests to see if there is space there for it.  If not, line #3052 moves the picker below the field instead. Simply commenting out line #3051 will cause the method to ALWAYS move the picker below the field.

If you have further questions or problems using Any+Time(TM), try using the contact page on [www.AMA3.com](http://www.ama3.com/) for a faster response!